# What's the difference between compiling/linking in one command, and compiling/linking in separate commands?

Tags: build, makefile

I have a makefile for a project where the executable is performance sensitive, and contains a lot of inline asm sequences as well as some C code that calls those sequences.  Right now we're building the executable by listing all the C files in a single compile/link command, like this:

```
gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) a.c b.c -o outfile
```

But this takes a long time to produce the executable.

Is there any difference performance-wise in the resulting executable (outfile) to breaking up the compile & link, like this:

```
gcc $(CFLAGS) -c a.c -o a.o
gcc $(CFLAGS) -c b.c -o b.o
gcc $(LFLAGS) a.o b.o -o outfile
```

This would speed up the build because we would perform an incremental build, and we could also use make -j to parallelize the build.

BTW, we're using gcc 5.1+.

Comment: You might want to research what the idea of make and makefiles actually is. Hint: your first variant is the exact opposite. And gcc is not a linker or build-tool. Your question is neither gcc- nor C related.

Comment: Thanks, just edited.

Comment: I think my original post was confusing.  I just edited it.  The executable is performance sensitive (I don't want to change the build method if it makes the executable run slower).  I know I can improve the build speed by breaking up the build into separate steps, but I don't know if the resulting executable will be slower.

Comment: Put main in outfile.c, and make your Makefile a single line: `outfile: a.o b.o outfile.o`.  Let make's implicit rules to the work for you.  CFLAGS will be honored by the implicit rules, as will LDFLAGS and LDLIBS.  The single line Makefile will give you the incremental build, which will be identical to the non-incremental build.

Comment: Please leave a comment with a downvote, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building as in your first example doesn't make any use of *make*'s ability to re-build only modified files. You are compiling *everything* *all the time*, then link.

Provided you use *make*, (it looks like so, although your first example line doesn't benefiit at all from it), you will only compile *modified* source files. In all *incremental* cases, that would actually result in a performance boost (amount depending on amount of modified source files between builds).

In release builds, however, where you would generally be expected to build *everything* *(make clean; make all)*, you couldn't expect a performance increase (you still do the same thing as originally), but could make use of make -j.

EDIT: After you changed the question:

No, there is no difference between the to build methods in terms of the resulting executable. Actually, the two resulting binaries should be 100% identical. Your first gcc line does exactly the same things as make + gcc would do with the modified makefile

Comment: I think my original post was confusing.  I just edited it.  The executable is performance sensitive (I don't want to change the build method if it makes the executable run slower).  I know I can improve the build speed by breaking up the build into separate steps, but I don't know if the resulting executable will be slower.